# Place mediaItemCollection data in UITableView

Tags: uitableview, xcode4, mpmediaitemcollection

I need some help placing the `mediaItemCollection` data in a `UITableView`.

Code:

```
// Responds to the user tapping Done after choosing music.
- (void) mediaPicker: (MPMediaPickerController *) mediaPicker didPickMediaItems:(MPMediaItemCollection *)mediaItemCollection {    
    [self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated: YES];

    [musicPlayer stop];
    [[MPMusicPlayerController iPodMusicPlayer] stop];
    [[MPMusicPlayerController iPodMusicPlayer] setQueueWithItemCollection:mediaItemCollection];
    [[MPMusicPlayerController iPodMusicPlayer] play];
}
```

The `mediaItemCollection` is what I need to place into my `UITableView`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[I found the code](http://media.pragprog.com/titles/amiphd/code/MediaLibrary/MusicLibraryClient/Classes/FlipsideViewController.m) :)

By declaring an `MPMediaItemCollection` and setting its content, I can read the `mediaItemCollection` when updating the `UITableView`'s data.

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"song_cell"];

    cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc]
            initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle 
            reuseIdentifier:@"song_cell"];

    MPMediaItem *anItem = [[collection items] objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    cell.textLabel.text = [anItem valueForProperty:MPMediaItemPropertyTitle];
    cell.detailTextLabel.text = [anItem valueForProperty:MPMediaItemPropertyArtist];

    [tableView reloadData];
}
```